# My Code skips the else statement of If-Else block

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I wrote a Caesar cipher using dictionaries. The code works perfectly until a character which is not a part of the dictionary such as a whitespace or comma is entered. I decided to handle those exceptions with an else statement but the code keeps skipping the else statement and returns the error :

> "Key Error: ' '".

```
Actual_Key = {"A":0, "B":1, "C":2, "D":3, "E":4, "F":5, "G":6, "H":7, "I":8, 
"J":9, "K":10, "L":11, "M":12, "N":13, "O":14, "P":15, "Q":16, "R":17, 
"S":18, "T":19, "U":20, "V":21, "W":22, "X":23, "Y":24, "Z":25}

Reverse_Key = {0:"A", 1:"B", 2:"C", 3:"D", 4:"E", 5:"F", 6:"G", 7:"H", 
8:"I", 9:"J", 10:"K", 11:"L", 12:"M", 13:"N", 14:"O", 15:"P", 16:"Q", 
17:"R", 18:"S", 19:"T", 20:"U", 21:"V", 22:"W", 23:"X", 24:"Y", 25:"Z"}

encrypted_message = ""

message = input("Please enter your message: \n> ").upper()
key = int(input("Enter a key number between 0 and 26 \n> "))

for letter in message:
    if letter in message:
        new_value = Actual_Key[letter] + key

        if new_value >= 26:
            new_value = new_value - 26

        citext = str(Reverse_Key[new_value])

        encrypted_message += citext

else:
    encrypted_message += letter

print (encrypted_message)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Letter` will ALWAYS be in `message`, as it's coming from it. So your first if statement is always true.

You need to check if `letter` is in your dictionnary.

```
for letter in message:
    if letter in Actual_key:
        new_value = Actual_Key[letter] + key

        if new_value >= 26:
            new_value = new_value - 26

        citext = str(Reverse_Key[new_value])

        encrypted_message += citext

    else:
        encrypted_message += letter

print (encrypted_message)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not indented correctly - the `else` statement needs to be indented under the `if`, not the `for`. Currently, the wrong indentation makes it an `else` clause **for the `for` clause`, which means it will be executed after the`for` loop terminates correctly.

```
for letter in message:
    if letter in message:
        new_value = Actual_Key[letter] + key

        if new_value >= 26:
            new_value = new_value - 26

        citext = str(Reverse_Key[new_value])

        encrypted_message += citext

    else: # Note the indentation here!
        encrypted_message += letter
```

Comment: Also I think the conditional should be `if letter in Actual_Key:`

Comment: Identation is probably just a pasting mistake. The actual problem is the first if statement that will always be true

Answer (score 0):

looks like you haven set the right indention. The else-statement should be on the same level than your if statement:

```
for letter in message:
    if letter in message:
      new_value = Actual_Key[letter] + key

      if new_value >= 26:
        new_value = new_value - 26

      citext = str(Reverse_Key[new_value])

      encrypted_message += citext

    else:
        encrypted_message += letter

print (encrypted_message)
```